# Trouble with a sortedInsert into a singly LinkedList.of Objects with attributes Java

Tags: java, sorting, singly-linked-list

This method will create a new Node object and insert it in order by the 3rd value in the CSV(i.e. KYZ98765, ABC12345, etc.)  it works except for the last node insert...

**Here is my code:**

```
void sortedInsert(Node new_node)
{
     Node current;

    /* Locate the correct node before inserting. */

    //System.out.println(current.data);
    if(head.next == null)
    {
        new_node.next = head;
        head = new_node;
        System.out.println("Inserted head: \n" + head.data.toString());
    }else
    {
        current = head;

        while (current.data.getbLnum().compareTo(new_node.data.getbLnum())>=0)
        {
            System.out.println("here again");  
            current = current.next;
        }
        new_node.next = current.next;
        current.next = new_node;
        System.out.println("Inserted: \n" + current.next.data.toString());
    }

 }
```

**Here is the output:**

FundManagerLicense   FundManagerLastname   FundManagerFirstname
  ABC12345               Wonch                Bob
 FundManagerLicense   FundManagerLastname   FundManagerFirstname
  ZYK98765               Ferguson                Jesus
 FundManagerLicense   FundManagerLastname   FundManagerFirstname
  GYZ98765               Ferguson                Jose
 FundManagerLicense   FundManagerLastname   FundManagerFirstname
  KYZ98765               Ferguson                Jimmi

**This is my input in the order each element is fed to the sortedInsert:**

BROKER,ADD,KYZ98765,Jimmi,Ferguson,321-131,0.02

BROKER,ADD,ABC12345,Bob,Wonch,321-112,0.1

BROKER,ADD,GYZ98765,Jose,Ferguson,321-111,0.02

BROKER,ADD,ZYK98765,Jesus,Ferguson,321-141,0.02

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
private int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
    return n1.data.getbLnum().compareTo(n2.data.getbLnum());
}

void sortedInsert(Node newNode) {
    Node prev = null;
    Node next = head;

    while (next != null &&
            compare(newNode, next) >= 0) {
        prev = next;
        next = next.next;
    }

    if (prev == null) head = newNode;
    else prev.next = newNode;
    newNode.next = next;
}
```

It should be fairly self-explanatory, go through the list, keeping track of the nodes that will come before (`prev`) and after (`next`) the inserted node, until `next` is null, or until `newNode` cannot come after `next`. Then insert the new node and, if necessary, make it the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a big risk of a null pointer exception.

```
while (current.data.getbLnum().compareTo(new_node.data.getbLnum())>=0)
        {
            System.out.println("here again");  
            current = current.next;
        }
```

When you reach the end of your list current will become null and the next call to current.data will throw and exception.

Do you know why is not being thrown? Because you made your list a circular list!

```
new_node.next = head;
    head = new_node;
```

The new node is the head and point to itself as next. So your last insertion goes all the way to the end f the list, fails to find an insertion place (because your last input should be placed at the end of the list) and then became the next after the head.

To solve the problem you need two changes:

```
void sortedInsert(Node new_node){
 Node current;

/* Locate the correct node before inserting. */

//System.out.println(current.data);
if(head.next == null)
{
    new_node.next = **null**;
    head = new_node;
    System.out.println("Inserted head: \n" + head.data.toString());
}else
{
    current = head;

    while (current.data.getbLnum().compareTo(new_node.data.getbLnum())>=0 **&& current.next != null**)
    {
        System.out.println("here again");  
        current = current.next;
    }
    new_node.next = current.next;
    current.next = new_node;
    System.out.println("Inserted: \n" + current.next.data.toString());
}
}
```

Test them and let me know.

Comment: Now it continues to put everything into head giving me a list of 1 object.